# How to display the user's game score on-screen in realtime, instead of in an alert at the end?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a score alert and it pops up at the end of my game, stating how many coins you won (200, 300, etc.). I want it to be counting the coins while playing the game, so for it not to appear at the very end.

My question is how to get this to appear on screen; not in the format of an alert. I have a HTML `div`:

```
<div id= "score"></div>
```

Here's my JavaScript that calculates how many coins have been won:

```
function gameOver()
{
    alert ("You got  " + score + " coins")

    document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML ="Game Over!";
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block"; 

    setTimeout(messageHide, 5000); /* pop up appears when game is over */
}

var score = 0;
```

Comment: Your div has an id of "score" but you're looking for an element with an id of "popup"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a `div` with an `id` of `score`, you need to run this line of code *every* time the score updates, to write it to that `div`:

```
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
```

Where `score = 200` or similar.

Comment: I'd advise using .textContent instead of innerText, as innerText is an IE implementation that doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: @dsg That's a good point - you just reminded me of the reason why I tend to use `innerHTML` over `innerText` - thanks.

Comment: @dsg In fact, here's a shim I used once to fix compatibility issues with FF: `HTMLElement.prototype.__defineSetter__("innerText", function (sText) { this.innerHTML = sText; });`

Answer (score 1):

Give your div some css like so:

```
#score
{
    position: absolute;
    top: /*somewhere*/;
    left: /*somewhere*/;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Specify top and left where ever you want it.  The z-index will keep it on top of everything else.

Combining this with the suggestion above will give you a score that updates in real time and is always visible.

You can add additional style elements to make it fancy.